# PostgreSQL Calculation of percentage across 3 joins

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm looking at calculating a percentage value to indicate progress. I am joining data from 3 independent counts on the same column (but of different values). I am so close but it keeps giving me ZERO.

```
SELECT a.count1 / (a.count1 + b.count2 + c.count3) FROM
(SELECT count(*) AS "count1"
FROM "stitch_jira"."issues"
WHERE "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name" = 'To Do') a
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT count(*) AS "count2"
FROM "stitch_jira"."issues"
WHERE ("stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name" = 'In Progress')) b  
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT count(*) AS "count3"
FROM "stitch_jira"."issues"
WHERE ("stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name" = 'Done')) c
```

Any advice on why I'm getting a zero result here? It should yield "0.4..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite entire query using conditinal aggregation and cast to decimal/multiply by 1.0:

```
SELECT 
 1.0*(COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE fields__status__statusCategory__name='To Do'))/
 (COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE fields__status__statusCategory__name 
                   IN('To Do','In Progress','Done')))
FROM "stitch_jira"."issues"
```